# XPATH append text or new line

Tags: bash, xmllint

I want to append a new line or text in xpath/xmllint output

I tried a lot of ways but xmllint doesn't provide much control on the output

find . -type f -name pom.xml|xargs -n 1 /usr/bin/xmllint  --xpath "/*[name()='project']/*[name()='groupId']/text()|/*[name()='project']/*[name()='artifactId']/text()|/*[name()='project']/*[name()='version']/text()"

output of each pom file in a new line instead of a whole big string

Comment: Did you try adding `-n` to the end of the xmllint command? I can't remember if that was an option with xmllint or xmlstarlet. I think it might've been xmlstarlet :-(

Answer (score 0):

May be.. not the best code

```
for file in `find . -type f -name pom.xml`
do
/usr/bin/xmllint --xpath "/[name()='project']/[name()='groupId']/text()|/[name()='project']/[name()='artifactId']/text()|/[name()='project']/[name()='version']/text()"
echo -e "\n\n\n" # add new line for each xpath
done
```

could you share the pom.xml file